# Discord bot not online

Tags: discord, bots

Im doing a course off UDEMY, how to create a discord bot that responds to messages, ive created the bot and all however, i am following all of the instructors  instructions yet his bot shows "online" and mine does not.

// token:
// invite link for bot: https://discord.com/api/oauth2/authorize?client_id=984130743578034216&permissions=2048&scope=bot

const Discord = require("discord.js");

const Client = new Discord.Client({ intents : ["GUILDS", "GUILD_MESSAGES", "DIRECT_MESSAGES"]});

Client.login("");

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, please provide any sort of code so we can help you.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: // token: (i have taken this out)
// invite link for bot: https://discord.com/api/oauth2/authorize?client_id=984130743578034216&permissions=2048&scope=bot

const Discord = require("discord.js");

const Client = new Discord.Client({ intents : ["GUILDS", "GUILD_MESSAGES", "DIRECT_MESSAGES"]});

Client.login(" i have taken this out");